# Does iOS 4.2 improve performance on the iPhone 3G?

Tags: iphone, ios, performance

I've "inherited" an iPhone 3G from a friend who upgraded to iPhone 4. He had complined about the slowness of iOS 4. Although I personally have no problems with it, I was wondering if iOS 4.2 offers any noticeable performance improvement. Does iOS 4.2 improve performance on the iPhone 3G?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the iLounge [article](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/instant-expert-secrets-features-of-ios-4.2/)

> Thus far iOS 4.2 appears to perform as
>   well as iOS 4.1 did under similar
>   conditions. Performance even on older
>   devices such as the iPhone 3G is the
>   same as iOS 4.1 and thus far we
>   haven’t observed any significant
>   changes in battery life.

Answer (score 0):

It actually seems faster than 4.1 to me on my 3G.

Answer (score 0):

My iPhone 3G has become slower in some occasions with iOS 4.2 especially when pasting an address from Mail to Maps.

Answer (score 0):

I have an iPhone 3G that I use for testing. 4.2.1 seems insanely slow on it, but maybe that's just because I've gotten so used to the speed of the 3GS and iPhone 4 over the past two years and forget what the "normal" speed of a 3G should feel like.

Comment: I told everyone that they have no room to complain when 4.0 came out. I used the 4.0 betas (part of the developer program) for nearly the first half of the year on my 3G. It was *miserable*. I really like 4.0, but I think that's because each beta was better than the last, so I got the opposite effect. Good -> Horrible -> Better.

Answer (score 0):

IOS4.2.1 is better than 4.1 for sure!!! I did not use yet the 3gs nor the iphone4, and got through every iOS "upgrade" available starting 3.1.3 , 4.0 , 4.0.1, 4.1 and probably yhe last one for the 3G 4.2.1 ! almost as fast as the 3.1.3 ,and with all the advantages of the 4.x ( folders, ibooks, faster maps, faster jawa, geo-tagging new caracters for notes, easier copy paste ((i think...)), etc. deffinatley a good option to upgrade! you will not be sorry!!!

Comment: Spelling, grammar, less special characters, and maybe even a newline or two. Please? Also, what the heck is jawa?

Comment: @Jason: they're those little people in robes that sell droids on the black market.

Comment: Well I knew that, but in-context what is sind talking about?

Answer (score -1):

My wife's 3GS which has 3.1.3 runs **much faster** than my 3GS with 4.3.5(BL1). However I *cannot* backup her unit in newly purchased MacBook Pro with Lion, but I *can* backup mine. I see it as Apple's way to force us to upgrade to their latest iOS even if that means to sacrifice performance. I don't like that at all, therefore I chose to backup 3.1.3 to a WinXP machine.